# RHEL ip n Connected Device has Stale Connection?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, rhel

When I run "ip n" on my RHEL box it lists a number of connected devices, all fine but one that reads:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx dev eth1 lladdr yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy STALE
```

What does STALE mean?

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question *may* be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se]. Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Answer (score 2):

It just means there has been no two-way communication with that IP address recently (usually over 30 seconds). This is useful information to keep as the cache is limited in size, so when space is needed stale entries are good candidates to remove.
There is some discussion of stale in `man 7 arp`.

You can see the 30 second timeout in file`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/p4p1/base_reachable_time_ms`.